# Alternating group problem in abstract algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

[image]

I understand the great majority of what the problem is asking. It asks:

We have two different permutations of length n and we want to show that the inverse of the inverse of the permutation of the permutation of these two different permutations are in the alternating group length n.

I'm having problems understanding this alternating group...I only know basic group theory and I'm not exactly sure what this means.

Here's an example of my understanding of the problem:

Let $ \begin{matrix} 1&2&3 \\ 2&3&1 \end{matrix}$ denote $\alpha$ and $\begin{matrix} 1&2&3 \\ 3&1&2 \end{matrix}$ denote $\beta$.

Then $\begin{matrix} 2&3&1 \\ 1&2&3 \end{matrix}$ denotes $ \alpha^{-1}$ and $ \begin{matrix} 3&1&2 \\ 1&2&3 \end{matrix}$ denotes $\beta^{-1}$.

Therefore $ \alpha^{-1} \circ \beta^{-1} \circ \alpha \circ \beta = 1 \ 2 \ 3$

And this is supposed to be in this $A_n$. But I'm not entirely sure why or what that means.

Comment: $\alpha\in A_n$ means $\mathrm{sign}\,\alpha=1$, that is, $\alpha$ can be written as a composition of an *even* number of transpositions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Background reminder:**

A transposition is a permutation that simply switches two entries, i.e. $\tau\in S_n$ is a *transposition* interchanging $i$ and $j$ (for $i\not=j$) if $\tau(i)=j$ and $\tau(j)=i$ and $\tau(k)=k$ for $k\not=i,j$.

Every permutation $\alpha\in S_n$ can be written as a product of transpositions.

Now one defines $\mathrm{sign}\,\alpha=(-1)^n$ if $\alpha$ can be written as a product of $n$ transpositions. This is a well-defined (!) group homomorphism $S_n\rightarrow \{\pm 1\}$.

$A_n$ can be defined as the set of all *even* permutations, i.e.

$$A_n=\{\alpha\in S_n\,:\,\mathrm{sign}(\alpha)=1\}$$

**Your problem:**

We have to show that $\gamma=\alpha^{-1}\circ\beta^{-1}\circ\alpha\circ\beta$ can be written as a composition of an even number of transpositions.

We know that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ can be written as products of transpositions, say $n$ and $m$ many, respectively. Then $\alpha^{-1}$ and $\beta^{-1}$ are also products of $n$, respectively $m$ transpositions (why?).

So we can write $\gamma$ as a product of $n+m+n+m=2(n+m)$ transpositions, i.e. $\gamma\in A_n$.

Comment: You lost me at $sign \alpha$. There is no word of this in my text book. What does this sign alpha have to do with my problem exactly?

Comment: And would I be correct that $\alpha^{-1}$ is also a product of $n$ transposition because it contains the same amount of elements?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by that. What I meant is that if $\alpha=\tau_1\circ\cdots\circ\tau_n$, then $\alpha^{-1}=\tau_n^{-1}\circ\cdots\circ \tau_1^{-1}=\tau_n\circ\cdots\circ \tau_1$ (transpositions are self inverse).

Comment: @user3200098: If your text book does not mention $\mathrm{sign}$ or transpositions, then how do they define $A_n$?

Comment: This is how my book defines it: http://imgur.com/zkhhPuD

I don't even understand half of what it says.

Comment: Please bear in mind that this is my first semester in a math b.sc. coming out of high school.

Comment: This is not the definition of $A_n$, this is the theorem stating that it is a group.

Comment: Well that's all I get in my book. It's called "Introduction to Abstract Algebra" by Malik, Sen. I searched the whole book for "Alternating Group" and that's the only time it mentions it outside the index on the last page.

Comment: In the paragraph just before that theorem it should give the definition of $A_n$.

Comment: I see, sort of...Why on earth does he make the connection so vaguely? I mean, it's probably great to read with a PhD and a thesis in group theory, but for a freshman just coming out of calculus...

Comment: @user3200098: Don't despair. As the great John von Neumann once said, "In mathematics you don't understand things, you just get used to them."